# Behaviour of Static Const and Const Variables in Global and in Class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

//In Globals.hpp

```
const int SINE_MIN = 0;    // only CONSTANT
const int SINE_MAX = 1;    // only CONSTANT

static const int COS_MIN = 1;   // STATIC CONSTANT
static const int COS_MAX = 0;   // STATIC CONSTANT
```

What are the difference between Static Const & Const Variable ?

And if Same Variables are declared in a Class.

```
class SomeClass 
{
    const int SINE_MIN = 0;    // only CONSTANT
    const int SINE_MAX = 1;    // only CONSTANT

    static const int COS_MIN = 1;   // STATIC CONSTANT
    static const int COS_MAX = 0;   // STATIC CONSTAN 
}
```

I want to Set value at runtime as `COS_MAX = getCosMaxFromFile()` and after that it should not be changed so Made it `Const` .

Comment: `static` controls storage and visibility, `const` controls whether something is writable or not.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Except here, where `const` also controls linkage (or "visibility", as you're calling it).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you declare something as `const` it means you can not change it. So no you can't assign to it in runtime. You can however call your function in the initialization:

```
static const int COS_MAX = getCosMaxFromFile();
```

Now then to the difference between `static` and non-`static` variables, it depends on *where* the variable is defined: If it's defined in file-global scope, or function-local scope. If it's in file-global scope then `static` variables are available only in the current [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (i.e. only in that source file). If it's a function-local variable, then a `static` variable will not loose its value between calls like other (non-static) local variables.

When you have a global `static` variable defined in a header file, that means that every source-file which includes the header file will have that variable defined. It won't cause linker errors though, because the variable is not visible outside each translation unit.

Comment: There is no need for 2nd of all in the post -> foreach(argument in arguments) if the arguments is a list of 1 item there will never be the second or third of all. (case closed).

Comment: But variables ≠ constants, especially when it comes to linkage (`const` implies `static`).